# Calculating odometry via angular velocity (for a two-wheeled robot)?

Tags: c, velocity, robotics

I need to program a robot to detect where it is, but because I have no external monitor/ camera, the robot needs to calculate its position internally. But I am unable to do this no matter how much research I do. Because the robot also needs to avoid obstacles, the velocity and direction are always in flux.

The code I've gotten so far is:

```
initX, initY (co-ordinates), initial Angle (0 radians)

omega = (rightSpeed - leftSpeed) * (radius of each wheel/ distance between wheels) Angle = Angle + omega

velocity = (rightSpeed + leftSpeed) / 2 distance = velocity * change in time

x' = x + (distance * sin(Angle)) y' = y + (distance * cos(Angle))
```

I'm using an Elisa-3 robot coded with Arduino (hence C) and this is the equivalent code:

[NB: `rightt` / `leftt` are speed values exclusive to Elisa-3. Multiplying them by "mySpeedUnit" converts them to "m/s" values. `PAUSE_1_SEC` is likewise the inbuilt equivalent of "1" second, thus `timeInSeconds` will always be the elapsed time in seconds. `radwheels` is the equivalent of (radius of wheel / distance between wheels). For some reason Arduino hates division if I'm not using inbuilt constant values, so I'm using a raw value here.]

```
//odometry //get current time and time elapsed

tempTime = getTime100MicroSec();

timeInSeconds = (tempTime - time)/PAUSE_1_SEC;

//angles

float r = rightt*mySpeedUnit;

float l = leftt*mySpeedUnit;

float omega = (rightt-leftt) * radwheels;

angle = angle + (omega*timeInSeconds);

angle = correct(angle);

//velocity

float v = (r+l)*0.5;

float s = v*timeInSeconds; //distance travelled

//x, y calculations using distance travelled

xpos = xpos + (s*sin(angle));

ypos = ypos + (s*cos(angle));

time = tempTime;
```

No matter how many times I code this, this robot refuses to co-operate, so I hope someone here will be able to help me. I'm willing to answer any questions you have to the best of my ability.

Comment: You have some calculations here. So you probably have some expected output for each of these for some given input. Can you locate the one which is not producing what is expected from it?

Comment: You goal is basically a chronologically discrete, 2D integration over time. The result is error-prone (because you will only have samples in a certain frequency) and will accumulate the error over time. Even if you manage to get the calculation basically correct, its precision will disappoint you sooner or later. The only way out is probably some kind of synchronisation scheme. I.e. you need to recalibrate your estimated position with the help of known markers. Luckily you mention obstacles. I recommend to reevaluate them as "useful landmarks".

Comment: By the way, please take some time to read help pages of this site. Start at the guided [tour], then [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: My favorite help for solving practically any problem: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: Oh, sorry for bringing that up last: Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Yunnosch That's fine. If there is another source of absolute position, these can be fused using Kalman filter or similar. It's ok to use odometry together with additional methods.

Comment: @EugeneSh. True. I consider that a (much more scientific and better phrased) other way of saying the same. Fusing/calibrating a less precise but absolute source with a more precise but integrating source is a great way. I admit to having lost it in the lecture after the luernberger observer. Kalman is magic. But at least I am sure it is white magic. ;-)

Comment: I get good results with odometer for right and left wheels on my 4-wheel car and angular velocity from an IMU. This works for some minute at a time. Integrating x and y accelerations deteriorates very quickly. Log your values, log everything a lot and inspect later.

Comment: I also suggest writing a small simulator which executes the same code with the same input. (I don't understand why they didn't put a 9-axis IMU into such an expensive thing.)

Comment: Was `omega = (rightSpeed - leftSpeed) * (radius of each wheel/ distance between wheels) Angle = Angle + omega`  meant to be on one line?

Comment: What does "Arduino hates division" mean?  Certainly 8bit AVR based Arduino lack a divide instruction and division is "expensive" in code ant time terms, but "hates" is ambiguous and non-technical.  What is the problem?  If it is the performance, then it takes into insignificance compared to sin and cos and floating point cide in general.

Comment: Moreover _"robot refuses to co-operate"_ is nonsense and _wrong thinking_. It is not an independent system, it is executing _your_ code.  You have to accept that your code is incorrect and stop blaming the inanimate.  "Inbuilt" is an odd term too.  None of that is "inbuilt", just defined elsewhere.

Comment: The reference to an external monitor/camera as if that is a usual and simple solution is irrelevant too.  It is by far not usual or simple - a harder problem that the one you are trying to solve in fact.